# Telegram Bot перестаёт получать обновления

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Добрый вечер! Написал бота для телеграмма на питоне. В процессе тестирования обнаружилось, что спустя неторое время работы он перестаёт получать обновления. И дело тут не в моём коде, а в самом telegram api, т.к. простое открытие https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/getUpdates в браузере возвращает json со СТАРЫМИ сообщениями. Т.е. бот-аккаунт ведёт себя так, как будто бы я в него ничего не пишу. При этом отправка сообщений через бота работает. Примерно через сутки получение обновлений возобновляется.

Сейчас я завел несколько бот-аккаунтов и при отключении одного просто меняю TOKEN на другой и работаю через другой аккаунт, но это не выход. Я не понимаю, почему так происходит и к кому надо обратиться.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ сам: в строку запроса надо добавить параметр

```
'?offset=<update_id>'
```

где update_id - ID последнего обновления.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а как Вы узнали update_id?